# Meteor - apply same onRender code for multiple templates

Tags: meteor

I am trying to code with DRY principle. I have multiple templates that should share the same onRender code:

```
Template.cardA.onRendered(function () {
  coolLogic()
});
Template.cardB.onRendered(function () {
  coolLogic()
});
```

Is it possible for me to avoid having to repeat `coolLogic()`?

Answer (score 1):

The only drier solution I can think of, is to drop the anonymous function around `coolLogic`.

```
Template.cardA.onRendered(coolLogic);
Template.cardB.onRendered(coolLogic);
```

Answer (score 1):

Template is an object, so you can iterate its members:

```js
_.each(["cardA", "cardB"], function(t) {
  Template[t].onRendered(function () {
    coolLogic()
  });
});
```